# I am unable to understand a piece of code I read. could anyone help me understand it

Tags: c#

I came across a code, which is bit confusing for me. In the below code, isVisible is not declared, still it is able to assign value to the delegate.

```
Action<bool> onChangeLoader = (isVisible) => { };
```

Comment: You've created an anonymous method (return type: void) which accepts a bool and does nothing. You've then stored that method as a delegate in `onChangeLoader`. `isVisible` is a bool as inferred from `Action<bool>`.

Comment: 1) [Delegates in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) 2) [Lambdas in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions) 3) [Delegates with Named vs Anonymous Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/delegates-with-named-vs-anonymous-methods)

Comment: Action<bool>  onChangeLoader  means is that  onChangeLoader is a method pointer and this method has a parameter in type bool.  ( isVisible ) =>  this is an anonim method decleration. isVisible type come from left part of equal

Answer (score 1):

That code is equivalent to having this method:

```cs
private void DoSomething(bool isVisible)
{

}
```

and then assigning a delegate for that method to a variable:

```cs
Action<bool> onChangeLoader = DoSomething;
```

After that, anywhere that you might call the `DoSomething` method, you could invoke the `onChangeLoader` delegate.